# SQL Server 2014 views differences in code

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2014

when I see the code in the view designer it's different from the code showed when I script the view using "ALTER TO" new query editor. Just an example

In design mode:

```sql
SELECT * FROM products prd;
```

In new query editor:

```sql
SELECT * FROM products prd
INNER JOIN providers po ON prd_id=po.id
```

This seems too odd but its what I'm seeing (I thought that need new reading glasses).

Please someone has saw this?

Comment: *"Please someone has saw this?"* I have never seen this, no, but also, I don't go anywhere near the buggy, feature lacking, quirky designer *because* it's buggy, feature lacking and quirky. I, personally, suggest you do the same and forget the designer ever existed.

Comment: Thx for your blazing fast answer @Larnu but thing is which one SS uses? because sometimes I've detected the results of the view are from the designer query and sometimes uses the scripted code. So, should I replace the designer code with the scripted code?

Comment: What is an "SS"?

Comment: SS=SQL Server, sorry

Comment: As I mentioned, the designer is buggy, feature lacking and quirky; I wouldn't trust it with anything.

Comment: Thx again @Larnu, then I'll delete the view and recreate with the script code.

Comment: I concur, nobody uses the designer, it's fundamentally broken. Learn to write views as `CREATE VIEW` statements and forget you ever knew it existed.